# Problem using link_to with remote option in rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on rails 3 with link_to remote option.

This is my code structure.

View/punch/report.html.erb :

---

```
<%= link_to 'Punch report', punchreport_punch_index_path, :remote => true%>
<div id="punchform"> </div>
```

View/punch/punchreport.js.erb :

---

```
$("#punchform").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "reportform"))%>");
```

and created a form inside

View/punch/_reportform.html.erb

and controller :

controller/punch_controller.rb

---

```
def report

end

def punchreport
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render report_punch_index_path }
   format.js 
  end
end
```

note :  punchreport_punch_index_path : /punch/punchreport

```
    report_punch_index_path     : /punch/report
```

I don get the ajax request working. instead of that, it redirects the page.

Any help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your :remote => true is not being handled by an unobstrusive javascript event handler...

Do you have something called jquery-rails in your project? it should set a handler on "data-remote" attribute. Can you find it and post back what you have there?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.0.9 and there is rails.js file included in the application. I'm getting follwing output :

Template is missing
Missing template /punch/punchreport with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rxml, :erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml]}

Comment: Included files are :

<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults%>

   <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "jquery.rails.js" %> 
 
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js' %>

   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

Comment: can you locate some kind of "data-remote" in your jquery.rails.js file? You should have something like this : 

    $('a[data-remote],input[data-remote]').live('click', function (e) {
        $(this).callRemote();
        e.preventDefault();
    });